# Bing maps - restrict panning to a boundary area

Tags: javascript, bing-maps

We need to let a user pan a map within a boundary.  The following code demonstrates one way to accomplish this by responding to the viewchangeend event. If the map has been panned out of the boundary, then it resets the location back to the last location recorded in the boundary area.

However, it's jumpy.  And I would like it to simply stop panning once the boundary has been reached.

Is there a way to accomplish this with Bing maps?

```js
var map;
var LastValidLocation, PanningRectLimit;

function GetMap() {

  var mapOptions = {
    center: new Microsoft.Maps.Location(29.771261, -95.364891),
    credentials: 'a valid api key',
    disableKeyboardInput: true,
    disableScrollWheelZoom: true,
    disableStreetside: true,
    disableZooming: true,
    enableClickableLogo: false,
    mapTypeId: Microsoft.Maps.MapTypeId.aerial,
    showDashboard: false,
    showScalebar: false,
    showTermsLink: false,
    tileBuffer: 2,
    zoom: 10
  };

  map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map(document.getElementById('myMap'), mapOptions);

  var pushpin = new Microsoft.Maps.Pushpin(map.getCenter());
  var layer = new Microsoft.Maps.Layer();
  layer.add(pushpin);
  map.layers.insert(layer);

  LastValidLocation = map.getCenter();
  PanningRectLimit = Microsoft.Maps.LocationRect.fromCorners(new Microsoft.Maps.Location(29.941359, -95.662621), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(29.583220, -95.077050));

  Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(map, 'viewchangestart', function(args) {});
  Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(map, 'viewchange', function(args) {});
  Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(map, 'viewchangeend', function(args) {
    restrictZoom();
  });
}

function restrictZoom() {
  var CurrentCenter = map.getCenter();
  if (PanningRectLimit.contains(CurrentCenter)) {
    LastValidLocation = CurrentCenter;
  } else {
    map.setView({
      center: LastValidLocation
    });
  };
};

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#centerButton').click(function() {
    map.setView({
      center: new Microsoft.Maps.Location(29.771261, -95.364891)
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.bing.com/api/maps/mapcontrol?callback=GetMap"></script>
<div id="myMap" style="width: 800px; height: 600px;"></div>
<button id="centerButton">Center</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, when loading the map set the maxBounds property to the bounding box in which you want to restrict the map view to. Here is a code sample: https://www.bing.com/api/maps/sdkrelease/mapcontrol/isdk#maxBounds+JS